# Row_number function

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I'm trying to update a column called `Rank` in `X table` where erank would be the rank of a column called `annual sales` and it is computed using `row_number () over (order by annual sales desc)` and as this is a function, hence it cannot be used to update as it should only be a part of select clause so we have written something like this :

```
UPDATE X 
   SET rank = SELECT acc_id,
                     annual_call,
                     ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY annual sales DESC)
                FROM x 
            GROUP BY acc_id,annual_call
```

**But this is throwing an error**

Comment: Could you post the error text as well?

Answer (score 4):

As general rule, when you ask a question and you mention an error, say **what** error you get. It help us help you, you don't have to make it a mystery novel...

Here is how you do it:

```
with cte as (
select [rank], row_number() over (
   partition by acc_id, annual_call
   order by [annual sales] desc) as [row_number]
from x)
update cte
set [rank] = [row_number];
```

Of course, persisting such rank is usually doomed since it will become incorrect after first update, but that is a different topic.

Answer (score 0):

Here while

```
set rank = select acc_id,annual_call,row_number () 
over (order by annual sales desc)
from x
```

must select only 1 column, you must implement some other logic for this. as assigning the values must return only a single column.